# Создание своего Класса Exception и выбрасывание исключения

Tags: java, исключения

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 5, b = 0;
        try{
            System.out.println(a/b);
        }catch (ArithmeticException e){
            throw new MyError();
        }
    }
}
```

Класс MyError для генерации собственного исключения

```
public class MyError extends Exception {
    @Override
    public void printStackTrace() {
        System.err.println("Ошибка ввода");
    }
}
```

Подчёркивает вот тут `throw new MyError();`
Я хочу чтобы при ошибки в try, в catch(e) генерировалось моё исключение и выдавало ошибку. Что не так делаю?

Comment: Обычно так делают, когда нужно залогировать и пробросить exception на уровень выше. Но в таком случае наследуются от `unchecked` `exception`, например, RTE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы наследуетесь от Exception. Exception относится к проверяемым исключениям. Ваша IDE намекает вам, что вы должны обработать его. Окружить блоком try catch:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 5, b = 0;
    try {
        try {
            System.out.println(a / b);
        } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            throw new MyError();
        }
    } catch (MyError myError) {
        myError.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

или добавить в сигнатуру метода:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws MyError {
        int a = 5, b = 0;
        try{
            System.out.println(a/b);
        } catch (ArithmeticException e){
            throw new MyError();
        }
    }
```

Кроме того, не стоит переопределять метод printStackTrace, если вам нужен вывод текста ошибки из вашего исключения, просто передайте его в конструкторе:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 5, b = 0;
    try {
        try {
            System.out.println(a / b);
        } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            throw new MyError("Ошибка ввода");
        }
    } catch (MyError myError) {
        System.out.println(myError.getMessage());
    }

}

class MyError extends Exception {

    public MyError() {
        super();
    }

    public MyError(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

a/b вызывает свой `ArithmeticException`, так как в операторе деления прописана проверка на ноль, примерно так

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int a = 5, b = 0;
  try{

    if(b==0) {
      throw new MyError();
    }
    System.out.println(a/b);
  }catch (MyError e){
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```